# Gatsby - Command failed with exit code 1: npm install

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to start my first Gatsby project but keep encountering the same error when creating a new project.

After running `gatsby new project-1`, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/tom.allen/.npm/_logs/2020-06-18T15_54_40_537Z-debug.log

 ERROR 

Command failed with exit code 1: npm install



  Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
  
  - error.js:56 makeError
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/lib/error.js:56:11
  
  - index.js:114 handlePromise
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:114:26
  
  - task_queues.js:97 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5
  
  - init-starter.js:139 async install
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:139:7
  
  - init-starter.js:206 async clone
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:206:3
  
  - init-starter.js:345 async initStarter
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/init-starter.js:345:19
  
  - create-cli.js:400 
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/create-cli.js:400:7
```

I have tried deleting the node_modules inside the project folder and running `npm i` again but I can't work out how to fix this issue. I'm on node v12.17.0 if that makes a difference... Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: try to clean your cache: ```npm cache clean --force``` and then rebuild your packages: ```npm rebuild```

Comment: What version of `gatsby-cli` are you running?

Comment: @FerranBuireu i'm using gatsby-cli@2.12.46

Comment: @demkovych I tried clearing the cache and rebuilding but doesnt seem to have fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

## Install nvm

> We strongly recommend using a Node version manager like nvm to install Node.js and npm. We do not recommend using a Node installer, since the Node installation process installs npm in a directory with local permissions and can cause permissions errors when you run npm packages globally.
> [npm's docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm)

1. If you have installed Node via some package manager or some Node installer, first of all, uninstall it and instead **install Node from nvm**. *In my case I had installed Node via NodeSource, so*:

   ```
   sudo apt purge node
   ```
2. Go ahead and install **nvm**, following the instructions on the [Github repo](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating). *I had to include the shell script manually in my `~/.zshrc` because the nvm script didn't do.*

## Install node and npm via nvm

1. Run the following to install Node and npm: `nvm install node`
2. Now, **in order to make `gatsby new` works**, you will need to install a previous version of node, which will be: v14.13.1. Run the following command and you will install the mentioned version:

   ```
   nvm install 14.13.1
   ```
3. Select the Node version to use if is not selected:

   ```
   nvm exec 14.13.1 node --version
   ```

## Gatsby

Now, you only need to install `Gatsby CLI`, and then simply use it.

1. Run the following: `npm install -g gatsby-cli`
2. Go to the folder where you want to create your project and then run:

   ```
   gatsby new [your-project-name] https://github.com/thomaswangio/gatsby-personal-starter-blog
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few suggestions:

- Hard cache removal: `npm cache clean --force`
- Upgrade `gatsby-cli` version: `npm update`
- Delete `node_modules` and `.cache` folder

Keep in mind removing `package-lock.json`to unlock you dependencies.